# Bring PHPdoc to include CakePHP .ctp files

Tags: php, cakephp, phpdoc

I'm documenting my CakePHP app using [PHPdocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/). As you might know, after CakePHP convention, the views are contained in .ctp files (e.g. app/views/addresses/index.ctp), which are basically normal PHP files just with a changed file extension. PHPdocumentor only recognizes .php files, and I cannot find an option in the config file to let it know of the .ctp files. THis section come closest to what I want:

```
;; comma-separated list of files to parse
;; legal values: paths separated by commas
;filename = /path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,fileincurrentdirectory
```

But as it seems it doesn't acceppt wildcards like `*.php`, and I really don't want to write a list of my 50 view files into this config file (unless there's a better solution).
Is there a possibility to configurate phpdoc globally to include .ctp files or do I have to change this in a somewhat hackish was somewhere in the phpdoc source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should update the [_phpDocumentor_phpfile_exts] section of your phpDocumentor.ini file to include any additional file extensions that you want phpDocumentor to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The comment says paths; nothing about file names. Maybe try adding the path to your `views` directory in the there, but if it is looking for `*.php` files then I don't think that will do much good.